# Design Enum generic behavior

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

Well my question today is:

- I have an enum with file headers.
- I have a function which export theses headers as String

Running multiple project I want to make it quite generic to be used in our private lib.

Current Function:

```
 private static String getHeaders() {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for(HeadersEnum header : HeadersEnum.values()){
        sb.append(header.getExportLib());
     }
     return sb.toString();
 }
```

**Goal** something like it:

```
 private static String getHeaders(ExportableCSV<Enum<T>> data) {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for( ExportableCSV<Enum> header : data.values()){
        sb.append(header.getExportLib());
     }
     return sb.toString();
 }
```

I know we can't make inheritance with Enum so I created an Interface "ExportableCSV":

```
public interface ExportableCSV<T extends Enum<T>> {

    public static final String exportLib = "";

    public static String getExportLib() {
        return exportLib;
    }

}
```

It's quite basic, but in my mind , **any Enum which implement this ExportableCSV should have access to my exportLib() function**.

```
public enum HeadersEnum implements ExportableCSV<HeadersEnum>{
    foo("foo;"),
    bar("bar;");


private String exportLib;
```

of course my goal approach of generic function isn't compiling and I'm not really understanding what I can do and what I can't.

Comment: How about having those `Enum` implement `interface Exportable {
 String getExportLib();   
}` ?

Comment: @c0der it's quite I did no ? 
With HeaderEnum implements Exportable witch have getExportLib()

Comment: Yes, but `Exportable` is different than `interface ExportableCSV<T extends Enum<T>> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option is to have all relevant `Enum`s implement an export interfce

```
interface Exportable { String getExportLib(); }
```

Another option: If you want a static method that uses `values` you can do something like:

```
class EnumUtil {

    public static <T extends Enum<T>> String getExportLib(T[] aValues){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         for( T t : aValues){
            //todo 
         }
         return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but what's the matter of the name of interface ? 
Is there a difference if I name it Exportable or ExportableCSV ? There is something I don't get here..

Comment: Moreover something I don't get is I can't do anything with t object. I can't call t.getExportLib 

I'm missing something here to understand your answer sorry

Comment: `interface ExportableCSV<T extends Enum<T>>`   vs  `interface Exportable { String getExportLib(); }` is not just a name difference.

Comment: _"I can't call t.getExportLib"_  with the first option proposed you can.